# IPTABLES (Rate Limiting) port 3306

Tags: mysql, iptables

Is there a way to rate limit connections on MySQL 3306 by using IPTABLES? I'm thinking to allow 2 connection attemps to port 3306 every 5 minutes. Thanks

Comment: I have to ask why you'd want to do this.

Comment: we got some clients that run a desktop app that connects to mysql. we only want those desktop apps being able to connect and not dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Would it not be better to keep these restrictions within MySQL itself, rather than on the network level? According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html) you can limit the following server resources for individual accounts:

```
*  The number of queries that an account can issue per hour
*  The number of updates that an account can issue per hour
*  The number of times an account can connect to the server per hour
*  The number of simultaneous connections to the server an account can have
```

An example MySQL query to do this:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'francis'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
    ->          MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
    ->          MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
    ->          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

I'd personally prefer to keep this type of setting within the application itself, rather than trying to manipulate it without the applications knowledge. But from what I understand the other examples of using iptables should technically work too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$IPT -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 3306 --syn -m limit --limit 10/hour \

--limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT


$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


$IPT -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

I was interested enough to do a search, found [this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187) amongst others.  Looks like you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, depending on the application, limiting the amount of connections might not actually limit the amount of queries. There's nothing stopping the app from making hundreds of queries on a single connection, it's even best practice to do so.